Unable to cut\copy\paste ifles in Dolphin File Manager on Kubuntu 24.04
When I try to do this, I receive the following error in a banner across the top of the dolphin window.
"file:Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying"
I am on a fresh install of kubuntu 24.04.
EDIT:
After troubleshooting, I've discovered that /run/user/1000/doc  lacks write permissions. When I run these commands dolphin begins working again.
fusermount -u /run/user/1000/doc
chmod 0700 /run/user/1000/doc
xdg-document-portal.service removes the write permission again upon reboot though.
I'm new to linux, and not sure where to go from here.
